# Android O - android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED affected by BroadcastRecevier limitations?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

while reading about the new Android O limitations, I noticed that the Google Devs limited the use of BroadcastReceivers in the manifest. They use the term implicit and explicit BroadcastReceivers, but I can't quite figure out what they mean exactly. For example, I have an app which listens to changes in the calender using the *android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED* broadcast:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.CalendarReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED"/>

        <data android:scheme="content"/>
        <data android:host="com.android.calendar"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Would this receiver be affected by the new limitations when the app would target Android O?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> They use the term implicit and explicit BroadcastReceivers, but I can't quite figure out what they mean exactly

An implicit broadcast is a broadcast of an implicit `Intent` (e.g., `sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED))`). An explicit broadcast is a broadcast of an explicit `Intent` (e.g., `sendBroadcast(new Intent(this, WhyAreYouDoingThisReceiver.class))`).

> Would this receiver be affected by the new limitations when the app would target Android O?

It depends entirely on the sender.

In Android 7.0, the calendar provider uses this code for sending that broadcast:

```
private void doSendUpdateNotification() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PROVIDER_CHANGED,
            CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_REPLACE_PENDING);
    if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.INFO)) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Sending notification intent: " + intent);
    }
    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent, null);
}
```

That is an implicit broadcast. If the calendar provider does not change on Android O, you will no longer be able to listen to that broadcast in the manifest. Your workaround is to use `JobScheduler`, with a job set to monitor your desired `Uri` via `addContentTriggerUri()` on `JobInfo.Builder`.

Comment: Why you did not suggest to use a Content Observer and instead proposed a JobScheduler?

Comment: @FrankMonza: A `ContentObserver` requires a continuously-running process, which is something to avoid wherever possible (in part because it never is truly continuously-running).

Comment: Ok fair enough and thanks for making me discover the content trigger uri option in the Builder, never thought about that :)

Comment: Use the following `builder.addTriggerContentUri`to run the job:    
  
`static final Uri CALENDAR_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CalendarContract.AUTHORITY + "/");`  
`builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(CalendarContract.CONTENT_URI,JobInfo.TriggerContentUri.FLAG_NOTIFY_FOR_DESCENDANTS));`  
`builder.addTriggerContentUri(new JobInfo.TriggerContentUri(CALENDAR_URI, 0));`